# Responsive c3 chart in table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, c3.js

How to Add responsive C3 chart in table.

i want to create a table with responsive table with one of the cell is C3 chart. initial width and height of the cell is 200 and 50, if browser size changes it should also update the chart.

Here my problem is on initial load also chart is not rendering as expected, svg size rendering as 197 width and 18 height.

[chart Image for console sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26d5k.png)
looks like some margin is adding. how to ad responsive chart in table can any one help me.

App link : https://angular-rrxg7y.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

It can be resolved by resizing the chart whenever the table or div size changes using the `chart.resize();` method